# How to get and store timestamp in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, timestamp

How can I automatically send date/time info to my database when my form is submitted? I'm making a comment box, and I have a column in my "comments" table called "created" (which I've set as a "datetime" type) where I would like date and time information to be sent so I can display it with the comments on my page.

Is this something I would have to send from my page's code, or can I set up the database in a way that it automatically stores a time stamp every time it receives new data from the form? I'm using phpMyAdmin to manage my database, in case that helps.

This is the code I have right now for sending the form's information:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$required_fields = array("author", "body");
validate_presences($required_fields);

if (empty($errors)) {
    $author = mysql_prep($_POST['author']);
    $body = mysql_prep($_POST['body']); 
    $page_name = ($_POST['page_name']);

    $query  = "INSERT INTO comments (";
    $query .= "  author, body, page_name";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .= "  '{$author}', '{$body}', '{$page_name}'";
    $query .= ")";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($result) {
        redirect_to("new_admin.php");
    } else {
            // Failure
            $_SESSION["message"] = "There was an error that prevented the comment from being saved.";
    }
}
} else {
    $author = "";
    $body = "";
}
?>
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!!

Comment: Did you set a field named something like 'date_added' in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would look something like this:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO comments (";
$query .= "  author, body, page_name, date_Added";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= "  '{$author}', '{$body}', '{$page_name}', NOW()";
$query .= ")";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Also you may need to

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD date_added date time;
```

or you could have the database populate it for you by adding a column like so:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD date_Added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: thanks! do you know if there is a benefit to one or the other? or is it just about personal preference?

Comment: The only reason to use the first one is if you are going to want to backdate or forward date them. Otherwise use the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as it's fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

In your db table definition you can set a default value for fields, including timestamp/datetime on new rows and on updates. This means you wouldn't have to change the above code (given the above scenario).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html